# How to add an emoji button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emoji

So I already did this basically 1 year ago but I forgot how to do it, and its not working now though. Here is the [LINK](https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-emojis-react-app/#:%7E:text=To%20include%20it%20in%20your,use%20React%2016.8%20or%20higher!)
basically I have a like a **"smile emoji icon button"** and then when I click it I will pass the emoji in my text but it giving me now an error `undefined`. In the link you can see that it has same thing here.

```
import './App.scss';
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Picker from 'emoji-picker-react';

function App() {



    const [chosenEmoji, setChosenEmoji] = useState(null);

    const onEmojiClick = (event, emojiObject) => {
      setChosenEmoji(emojiObject);
      console.log(emojiObject)
    };
  
    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          
        {/* {isLogin && user ? <LoginTrue/> : <LoginFalse/>} */}
        {chosenEmoji ? (
          <span>You chose: {chosenEmoji.emoji}</span>
        ) : (
          <span>No emoji Chosen</span>
        )}
        <Picker onEmojiClick={onEmojiClick} />
      
        </header>
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

but the new update of `emoji-picker-react` did get different...Is anyone can give me an idea of it? or is there another source of importing emojis..I don't want to use `Input-emoji-react` its too ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it helpful but the way I personally did it on my project were I also used `emoji-picker-react` and `MaterialUI` is through native materialUI emoji icon button like this:

```
<div className="chat_footer">
        {!emojiPicker ? (
          <InsertEmoticonIcon onClick={() => setEmojiPicker((prev) => !prev)} />
        ) : (
          <>
            <InsertEmoticonIcon
              onClick={() => setEmojiPicker((prev) => !prev)}
            />
            <EmojiPicker
              searchDisabled="true"
              previewConfig={{ showPreview: false }}
              emojiStyle="google"
              onEmojiClick={(e) => setInput((input) => input + e.emoji)}
              height={400}
              width="40%"
            />
          </>
        )}
```

As I said, `InsertEmoticonIcon` is a MaterialUI icon which I `import`

Comment: sorry I don't use materialUI can you add it in the codes as well? I don't get it.

Comment: You have to install MaterialUI first and then import the emoji icon like `import InsertEmoticonIcon from "@mui/icons-material/InsertEmoticon";`
But I guess installing MaterialUi just for an icon is kind of an overkill

Comment: no its ok..I no worries.

Comment: its like this right `npm install @material-ui/core` ? @Marios

Comment: I think you can install just the Icons and not thw whole MaterialUI as I can see from here:
[https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/]

`npm install @mui/icons-material @mui/material @emotion/styled @emotion/react`

Comment: I have one last question...How can I make the EmojiPicker style position absolute? I don't want to taken the height of it in a web design...I want it to be an absolute..Is there any possibility I can do that bro?

Comment: I did try something like this @Marios `style = {{width:"300px",height:'350px',position:'absolute'}}` but its not working out in the EmojiPicker

Comment: @MYTH in your css have this `.EmojiPickerReact.epr-main {
  position: absolute !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Code sandbox link:
This link may help:
https://codesandbox.io/s/emoji-picker-react-4-forked-h846rd?file=/src/App.tsx

Onclick handler has to be Emoji and Event, not Event and then emoji